# React unexpected number rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbreact

I have the following React example, and I'm trying to show a success toast (from mdbootstrap library) every time the isShowing state is true.  This works as expected regarding the toast, but a number is displayed next to the button, and increments after each click. This number also appears as a children of the main div from the App file ( See attached image and codesandbox link) .
Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Nav from "./Navbar";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import Mes from "./Message";
import { Button, toast } from "mdbreact";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isShowing: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isShowing: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Mes />
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          show Alert{" "}
        </Button>
        {this.state.isShowing ? toast.success("Success message") : ""}
        <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/l2xqplx4rm

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to render `toast.success` in your code. Remove

```
{this.state.isShowing ? toast.success("Success message") : ""}
```

In above code case your binding the toast's `toast.success` methods response which is nothing but the active toast length. So its displaying number over there.

Just below code is enough to show toast on button click.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Nav from "./Navbar";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import Mes from "./Message";
import { Button, toast } from "mdbreact";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

  handleClick = () => {
     //show toast
     toast.success("Success message");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Mes />
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Show Alert
        </Button>
        <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is updated [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/m307z9l6y)